# How to clear the whole AEM dispatcher cache in a cloud manager deployment

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I'd like to configure the Adobe Cloud Manager [production pipeline](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-manager/content/using/pipelines/production-pipelines.html?lang=en) to invalidate the whole dispatcher cache. What paths do I have to give at the production pipeline dispatcher invalidation configuration to have that done? Is it possible to give a pattern here that matches everything? The [page-invalidate](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/page-invalidate.html?lang=en) description talks about a path-pattern, but doesn't describe what exactly that means.

We work with statfilelevel=2. It seems the .stat files are very important for that, though the description [given here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html?lang=en) is unfortunately not precise enough, not sure I understand that right.

- I tried to configure /content as path - that just touches /mnt/var/www/html/.stat (/mnt/var/www/html is the docroot), which seems to apply to nodes like /* but not like /content/* .
- If I give /content/oursite, that touches /mnt/var/www/html/content/.stat , too, but that does seem to apply to nodes like /content/oursite or /content/othersite, but not to pages like /content/oursite/about - for which would /mnt/var/www/html/content/oursite/.stat be relevant, if I understand that right.

Do I seriously have to enumerate a page in each site that has a .stat file, or is there a more sensible way to get everything invalidated? After all, a deployment could easily change the HTML of every page if a component has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ACS commons installed then you can try to use this powerful feature

https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/dispatcher-flush-rules/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I can see how you can use this to be more flexible in invalidation when you're publishing something. But how would you use that when deploying, as that'd normally not publish something or even change anything in /content?

Comment: when you deploy, the content package is replicated to /etc/packages. You can right rule for that. See this https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/dispatcher-flush-rules/index.html#global-config-example

Or you can write custom rule to invalidate/delete cache of entire /content on publishing a particular page.

You can accept this answer and upvote so that others can make good of use it in such scenarios.

Comment: you can also write a custom workflow or custom listeners